# Confidence intervals on parameter estimates for an ATF model in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, survival

UPDATED with dataset and code: [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10uwpRBoncgNbwuO-WKLQmYNbQIEvrJZo/view?usp=sharing) [code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-38ZWGSVPaeiPztp1zNLwLldZ1c_gMMg/view?usp=sharing)

I have a Cox regression and an ATF regression with the same covariates and dependent variables in R; that is, the only difference between the two is the modeling function. I'm trying to get the confidence interval for each parameter estimate using `confint()`. I'm not referring to the confidence bands of the survival curve/probability, but rather the CI around each parameter estimate.

The Cox model:

```
os_coxph <- coxph(os_surv ~ age_lot1 + gendermale + racegpBlack + racegpOther
                  + risk_cytogenetic1 + risk_cytogenetic2
                  + dxStageI + dxStageII + dxStageIII + dxLeukemia
                  + lot_rxcnt_1_1 + sctLOT1 + sctLater + lag46plus + cluster(UID),
                  weights=wt, data = test)
confint(os_coxph)
```

The ATF model (Weibull distribution):

```
os_tfw1 <- survreg(os_surv ~ age_lot1 + gendermale + racegpBlack + racegpOther
                   + risk_cytogenetic1 + risk_cytogenetic2
                   + dxStageI + dxStageII + dxStageIII + dxLeukemia
                   + lot_rxcnt_1_1 + sctLOT1 + sctLater + lag46plus + cluster(UID),
                   weights = wt, data = test)
confint(os_tfw1)
```

The former (Cox) outputs:

```
                        2.5 %    97.5 %
age_lot1           0.01868637 0.1679876
gendermale        -0.66575169 0.6323086
racegpBlack       -0.90640810 4.2957683
etc.
```

All as expected. But the latter (ATF) outputs full of NAs:

```
                  2.5 % 97.5 %
(Intercept)          NA     NA
age_lot1             NA     NA
gendermale           NA     NA
racegpBlack          NA     NA
```

I also have a similar logistic regression model and it has no problem outputting the confidence intervals for the parameter estimates.

Is `confint()` unable to take ATF models as an argument? Or is there something I'm missing? Is there an alternative that works on ATF models fit with `survreg`? TIA.

Comment: could we have a [mcve] please ... ?

Comment: Could [this package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ciTools/vignettes/ciTools_survreg_vignette.html) be of any help?

Comment: I did eventually find out that `confint()` should be able to take `survreg` models as an argument. With that information I'd like to do a little more digging into what's going on so that I can post a more intelligent question to follow up. I'm working on it!

Comment: @FrancescoGrossetti I had looked at that, and unfortunately, my model is (has to be) weighted.

Comment: @BenBolker I've updated the question with the dataset and code. So far I have identified that it appears to have something to do with the two "continuous" covariates, `age_lot1` and `rxcnt_1_1`. All the rest of the covariates are dummies. As soon as I put in either of these variables the ATF CIs go all NA.

Comment: In "this is so dumb" department - I just tried running the exact same script on another machine and it has no problem. The original machine is running R version 3.6 due to some OS constraints but the PC is running R version 4. I guess `confint()` had some issues in 3.6? Thanks everyone for your help/willingness to help!